# PHP form output saving in excel sheet by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In my website there is a PHP enabled form  for the Address details. The out put is posted  in my email box. I like the out put to be saved in my external excel file "address.xls"  by way of Jquery /json.  The input fields of PHP form is" NAME", "ADDRESS", "CITY", "PHONE", "FAX", "EMAIL". Any body help in this case.

Through the website form, the Name, address, City, Phone,Fax, Emails are being saved in the PHP enabled E-mail. But I like that to be saved in a excel sheet which will be better for sorting or database.

Also auto reopen and append the last row by default.

Comment: Why is jquery/json needed?  Wouldn't any technique that results in an excel sheet help?

Comment: there's no widespread way of doing this directly from the browser with javascript. You have to post the data to the server and do it with php.

Comment: You may also do it by the means of a Java applet.

Answer (score 0):

POST the data to a php script like I believe you are doing.. then have the script look like this

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: application/ms-excel");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myTable.xls"); 

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $address = $_POST['address'];
  $city = $_POST['city'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];


  echo "name \t address \t city \t phone \n";
  echo "$name \t $address \t $city \t $phone";

?>
```

Comment: If you are collecting data multiple times and want to keep adding to the table, you should really use a database. But if you want to use a flat file then just save it each time to a tab delimited text file, and reopen and append the last row each time

Comment: Is the output data of PHP form will be saved in sequential manner or saved on the same data?